# VB.net dynamic table ID

Tags: vb.net

I'm dynamically populating a table via VB.NET using jQuery and ajax but I need the physical table ID to change to fire table specific events on the front end that will be recognized by jQuery.

I've googled and tried passing a variable without any any success. It is possible to load a table dynamically and change the displayed ID in vb.net?

```
<asp:Table ID="<%=dynamicTableID%>" runat="server"> </asp:Table>
```

any feed back ins appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You're trying to get the table ID in jQuery, yes?

Comment: Have you tried the .ClientIDMode property?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `data` attributes for something like this. Instead of parsing out a dynamic id you can do something like

```
<asp:Table ID="<%=myId%>" runat="server" data-src="<%=someUniqureAttr%>"> </asp:Table>
```

You can access this field in jquery like this

```
$('table').data("src")
```

And use a selector like this

```
$('table[data-src="myUniqueAttr"]')
```

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately I'm getting Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs. regardless of what field I'm trying to dynamically set.

Comment: @paxx I'm not familiar with using asp but [this](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?3724-Error-Server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs-in-ASP-NET-MVC) says that maybe using single quotes may work?